# Search specific text in string and get specifc part of the string

Tags: python

I'm learning Python slowly and trying to see how work with strings on it.

Already know how to split strings, search for specific text and characters inside string, etc..

I wonder how could a go for the follow situation:

Search for a specific "word" in a string, and when find the word, jump X characters and save in a variable all the content until the next "

Just a little example of the situation:

```
metric="123"submetric='234232423'cpu="A2324324324242423B"Memory="12sdfa3"HD="23423234242423"TEMP="A3243242423B"metric="adsdf123"submetric='232423'cpu="A2324324dafdas324242423B"Memory="12s3"HD="234232456634242423"TEMP="A324324644242423B"
```

In the situation above, search for "metric,submetric,cpu,memory,hd and temp" and save their results.

Comment: Why not try it, and ask for help with the part you get stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import re

mystr = 'metric="123"submetric="234232423"cpu="A2324324324242423B"Memory="12sdfa3"HD="23423234242423"TEMP="A3243242423B"metric="adsdf123"submetric="232423"cpu="A2324324dafdas324242423B"Memory="12s3"HD="234232456634242423"TEMP="A324324644242423B"'

lst = re.split('=|"', mystr)
indices = [i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j=='Memory']
values = [lst[i+2] for i in indices]  # ['12sdfa3', '12s3']
```

Comment: Thanks!!
With my little knowledge about on the language the far I could go was the example below. 

Your example does exactly what I was looking for, imma study it to get how it works

Thks again

> m = "metric"
> strline = metric="123"submetric='234232423'cpu="A2324324324242423B"Memory="12sdfa3"HD="23423234242423"TEMP="A3243242423B"metric="adsdf123"submetric='232423'
strindex = strline.find(m)
> result = ""
> for c in list(strline[(strindex + len(m) + 2):]:
> if c == '"':
>  break
> else:
>  result = result + c
> print m + "=" + result